# Saving large files (over 20 MB) in Access database with SQL Server back end fails

Tags: sql-server, object, ms-access, vba, ole

I have an application with Microsoft Access front end and SQL Server back end.  The link is implemented via ODBC data source using SQL Server Native Client 11.0.

There is a table with a column Attachments of OLE Object data type. The back end is a table with VARBINARY(MAX) data type for the Attachments column.
I save files in the Attachment field using Bound Object Frame.  Everything works fine until the file size exceeds about **20MB**.  The statement BoundOLEFrame.Action = acOLECreateEmbed takes about 2.5 minutes to complete. It does not throw any exceptions, but when the following MoveNext or any recordset re-positioning statements is performed, they fail with Run-time error "3426":

> "The action was cancelled by an associated object."

As the result the file does not appear to be stored in the database.  An attempt to open the file with Access UI by double-clicking on the field causes the error:

> "A problem occurred while Microsoft Access was communicating with the
>   OLE server or ActiveX Control. Close the OLE server and restart it
>   outside of Microsoft Access. Then try the original operation again in
>   Microsoft Access."

Suspecting that the issue could be related to ODBC timeout, which is by default is set to 60 seconds, I tried to set the current database QueryTimeout to 600 seconds. But this did not help...

Inserting these large files directly in the table (in Access table datasheet view, right-clicking on the field and selecting *Insert Object...* in the pop-up menu) first appear as successful, because the file looks like it was inserted and could be opened by double-clicking on the field.  But, when I try to close the table, I am prompted if I wish to save it.  Answering in affirmative leads to the following error:

> "You can't save this record at this time. Microsoft Access may have
>   encountered an error while trying to save a record.  If you close this
>   object now, the data changes you made will be lost.  Do you want to
>   close the database object anyway?"

According to [Access specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854) the size of an OLE Object field is 1 GB, which is well above the size of my files.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I am looking for a way to resolve this particular problem.  I don’t think that alternative design for file storage is pertinent to the topic.

**I do not have an option to store files any other way.**

Comment: If I were you, I'd share all the associated code, since it's pretty unorthodox code. I will try to repro in the mean time

Comment: Hmmm... I actually can't save OLE objects that large at all, even when directly inserting them into an unlinked table through the GUI. I'm getting an _You can't save this record at this time_ error.

Comment: Yes.  I am getting the same.  But, this is not an issue with SQL Server, as I could save the same files there as a byte stream (the very comparable size), but then I could not open them just by double-clicking on the field.  For that I need them to be OLE objects.

Comment: Nope, it's all Access. I've done a quick test under Access 2010 and 2016, both with local storage, and both can't save an OLE Package over 20 MB. OLE blobs (Long Binary Data) can go up to 1 GB, though, and larger if you link them directly to SQL server.

Comment: How would I save as OLE blob?  Would I be able to open it by double-clicking?

Comment: No, you wouldn't. It's the recommended way of saving it though, and I believe you were using that (with an ADODB.Stream) in your previous question. You can only work with it through VBA (since it's just binary data, without a filename or file type or any other context).

Comment: Is there a way to handle the double-click event on the field in the table grid view and write a special handler which would take the byte stream from the field, save it as a file and open it appropriately?  I guess I would be able to write the handler.  I just need to know how to bind it to the event, if it is possible.

Comment: Only if you use a form in datasheet view instead of the table itself. If you directly use the table, you can't use VBA

Comment: Erik von Asmuth, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well the OLE Object field size max may be 1G - - but the overall file size for Access is 2G.

so if you have more than 100 x 20M fields - then there is going to be a problem.

it's unclear how many records are actually transferring to the front end file.  I would sanity test a very limited set of records to see whether it is the field size or the overall file size that is coming into play.... perhaps that will give some insight.

I can tell from your post that you DON'T want me to suggest putting those attached files in their own folder and just store the link - but hey - it is the better design.....

Comment: Cahaba Data, I hope you have noticed that the data actually stored in SQL Server. Whether this causes issues with Access 2016 32-bit database size limitation or not, I don't know.

Comment: I have implemented an alternative solution where the saved file size does not exceed 20 MB.  However, i still have major issues with Access as a front end platform.  The program just freezes.  No errors or exceptions.  Just stops responding.  Debugging the Assembly code shows that Access goes in some endless loop.  Very frustrating.

Comment: My concern/advice is in regard to a PC app (Access) being the front end to potentially a mainframe size back end.  One must consider the weakest link - or perhaps the better analogy is a fire hose connecting to a garden hose.  SQL Server definitely can hold the data - but if too much is transferring into Access then that is the problem.  Access is a front end database technology - so all the logic processing is being done there.  I don't know the structure of your queries as to how many records are involved - each with a 20M attachment - but my instinct is that this is a data volume issue.